# Why wont a td that contains a div stretch to proper size IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, html-table

My markup is:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
  <tr>
    <td class="key">
      <div>Age:</div>
    </td>
    <td class="value">
      <div>69</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And my CSS is:

```
td.key
{
  border-left: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #7f7f7f;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  width: 115px;
}

td.key div
{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
```

"Computed Style" screenshots from Chrome for the TD element:

[image: The TD Element]

"Computed Style" screenshots from Chrome for the DIV child element:

[image: The DIV Element]

Now when this renders in Chrome I get this result:

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

When this renders in IE7 I get this result:

[image: IE7 Screenshot]

Not sure what I'm doing wrong any help would be great!

**NOTE:** The problem does not occur on IE8+

Comment: You clearly have padding on that td.

Comment: Start with a CSS reset. It goes a long way for compatibility issues.

Comment: Please view the edited description for the computed styles @BradM

Comment: CSS has already been reset @Diodeus

Comment: @wfoster Yeah, but we don't care about what chrome says the css is, we care about IE7. Set `padding-right: 0% !important;` for the td and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @BradM nope, that didn't fix it.

Comment: You might consider trying `clear:both;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply an attribute to only IE7 and below, you could use the `*` key like so:

```
td.key
{
  border-left: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #7f7f7f;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  width: 115px;
  *width: 105px;
}
```

This makes it so the width is 115 in all browsers, but once it's loaded in IE7 or below, it sets the width to 105px to cut off that extra space at the end.

*It's more of a workaround than a solution, but it's still valid.*